# DBMS_SCHEDULER calling a procedure using bind variables

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, bind, scheduler

Has anyone used bind variables in Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job while calling a stored procedure? My background of this question is based on following question: [Dynamic PL/SQL date parameter with time value retained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455867/dynamic-pl-sql-date-parameter-with-time-value-retained) Thanks.

Comment: Can you more completely describe the problem that you're having?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948960/oracle-calling-a-job-with-arguments